# Why does openpyxl not correctly apply number formats and styling to my Excel file in Python 3.11?

Tags: python, excel, format, numbers, openpyxl

How do you apply formats using openpyxl?

I have tried many suggestions based on openpyxl documentation and answers here and haven't gotten anything to work. As an example, this code is supposed to take a template document, input data, and then apply a number format to the numerical fields and stylize the header:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import shutil
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl.styles.numbers import builtin_format_code

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris = iris.rename(columns={'sepal_length': 'Sepal Length',
                            'sepal_width': 'Sepal Width',
                            'petal_length': 'Petal Length',
                            'petal_width': 'Petal Width',
                            'species': 'Species'})

main_path = rf"C:\Users\HaleighOeser\OneDrive - kyndryl\Documents\Misc_Projects\iris_template.xlsx"
new_path = rf"C:\Users\HaleighOeser\OneDrive - kyndryl\Documents\Misc_Projects\iris_modified.xlsx"
shutil.copy(main_path, new_path)
print('New File Created')

workbook = load_workbook(new_path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
iris.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Data')

sheet = workbook['Data']
num_rows = len(iris)

for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    for r in range(2, num_rows + 1):
        sheet[f'{c}{r}'].number_format = builtin_format_code(4)


for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
    sheet[f'{c}1'].alignment = Alignment(vertical='center', wrapText=True)

c = sheet['A2']
sheet.freeze_panes = c
writer.close()
```

The input file looks like this:
[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asvBa.png)

But in the output, the header is not vertically centered, and the numbers only have 1 decimal place:
[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS7la.png)

Does anyone know what would fix this problem or what I am doing wrong? I am using Python 3.11 and openpyxl 3.0.10

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you don't need a *template* here. I would do it this way with a mix of [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html)/[openypxl](/questions/tagged/openypxl) :

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris").rename(lambda x: x.replace("_", " ").title(), axis=1)

def color_headers(ser):
    return [
        "background-color: #e6b8b7;text-align: center;font-weight: bold"
        for _ in ser[:-1]] + [
        "background-color: #b1a0c7;text-align: center;font-weight: bold"
    ]

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    (iris.style
         .set_properties(**{"border":"1px solid", "text-align": "center"})
         .apply_index(color_headers, axis="columns")
         .to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=0, sheet_name="Data")
         # float_format="%.4f" seems to have no effet when passed `to_excel`
    )
     
    for idx, column in enumerate(iris.columns[:-1], start=1):
        for row in writer.book["Data"].iter_rows(
            min_row=2, min_col=idx, max_col=idx
        ):
            for cell in row:
                cell.number_format = u"0.0000"
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Really best to avoid using `get_column_letter()` in loops like this. `iter_rows()` is much better.

Comment: The enumerator is now useless. You can probably just use the length of columns.